# Access to a property with Interface cast

Tags: linq, entity-framework, interface

ActionBase, ActionA, ActionB and ActionC are Entities (from a database). ActionA, ActionB and ActionC are derived type of ActionBase.

ActionB and ActionC implements ISpecialAction with a SpecialProperty.

ex :

```
public interface ISpecialAction
{
    Guid SpecialProperty { get; }
}

public partial class ActionBase
{
    public objectX OnePropertyBase { get; set; }
}

public partial class ActionA : ActionBase
{
    public objectY OnePropertyA { get; set; }
}

public partial class ActionB:ActionBase,ISpecialAction 
{
    public objectZ OnePropertyB { get; set; }

    public Guid SpecialProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return OnePropertyB.ID;
        }
    }
}

public partial class ActionC : ActionBase ,ISpecialAction 
{
    public objectW OnePropertyC { get; set; }

    public Guid SpecialProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return OnePropertyC.ID;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that SpecialProperty is build from other Properties of the objects (ActionB or ActionC) and when the cast (to ISpecialAction) is done, OtherProperty and OtherProperty2 are null.
I tried :

```
GetActionBase().ToList().Where(x=>x is ISpecialAction && ((dynamic) x).SpecialProperty== p_SpecialProperty);
GetActionBase().ToList().Where(x=>x is ISpecialAction && ((ISpecialAction) x).SpecialProperty== p_SpecialProperty);
GetActionBase().ToList().OfType<ISpecialAction>().Where(x => x.SpecialProperty== p_SpecialProperty).Cast<ActionBase>();
return GetActionOnGoing().ToList().OfType<ICityAction>().Cast<ActionBase>().Where(x => ((dynamic)x).CityId == p_CityId);
```

remark : `OfType<>` doesn't works with an Interface in Linq to entities but is ok in Linq to object

How do I access my property interface without knowing the type of the object?

Comment: I assume you mean `OnePropertyA` and `OnePropertyB` in stead of `OtherProperty` and `OtherProperty2`? And that `OnePropertyA` and `OnePropertyB` are mapped properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might missed something but this is Ok with the code you provided :

```
public class objectX
{

}
public class objectY
{

}
public class objectZ
{
    public Guid ID { get { return Guid.NewGuid();} }
}
public class objectW
{
    public Guid ID { get { return new Guid(); } }
}

class Program
{
    private static Guid p_SpecialProperty;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = GetActionBase().ToList().Where(x => x is ISpecialAction && ((dynamic)x).SpecialProperty == p_SpecialProperty).FirstOrDefault();
        var result1 = GetActionBase().ToList().Where(x => x is ISpecialAction && ((ISpecialAction)x).SpecialProperty == p_SpecialProperty).FirstOrDefault();
        var result2 = GetActionBase().ToList().OfType<ISpecialAction>().Where(x => x.SpecialProperty == p_SpecialProperty).Cast<ActionBase>().FirstOrDefault();
                }

    private static IEnumerable<ActionBase> GetActionBase()
    {
        return new List<ActionBase> {new ActionA{OnePropertyA= new objectY()}, new ActionB{OnePropertyB=new objectZ()},new ActionC{OnePropertyC=new objectW()} };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I exactly understand your question, but could you try using an intermediate interface, such as:

```
public interface ISpecialActionB : ISpecialAction
{
    objectZ OnePropertyB { get; set; }
}

public class ActionB : ActionBase, ISpecialActionB
{
    //same stuff
}
```

and casting to that instead.

```
var b = new ActionB{OnePropertyB = new Whatever()};

var bAsSpecial = b as ISpecialActionB;

var whatever =  b.OnePropertyB; // should not be null
```

Answer (score 0):

It' ok.

Your example run very well without problem so I searched in a other way : AutoMapper.

```
l_List.Actions = Mapper.Map<List<ActionBase>, Action[]>(l_ActionManagement.GetActionBySpecialId(l_Special.ID).ToList());
```

The problem was not interfaces or Linq queries but it was that automapper need an empty constructor and in this constructor, I need to initialize OnePropertyB and OnePropertyC to compute SpecialProperty.

Thanks